# WP_Query - Order by Taxonomy term's meta data

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to order posts for a wp_query using the value of the term fir a specific taxonomy

Each Taxonomy term has a number from 1 to 10 set by meta data (using ACF)

```
$args = array(

    'post_type'         => 'post',
    'post_status'       => 'publish',
    'tax_query'         => array(
                      'relation' => 'AND',
                             array(
                                  'taxonomy'          => 'category',
                                  'meta_key'          => 'menu_order',
                                  'orderby'           => 'meta_value_num',
                             ),
                       ),
);
$wp_query = new \WP_Query($args);
```

Essentially each term has an order and I want the query to return all posts but in that order I've manually set!

Another solution I've tried is using https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-taxonomy-order-ne/ and the `'orderby' => 'term_order'` it gives

```
$terms = get_terms( 'category',array(
    'orderby'   => 'term_order'
));

$term_ids = wp_list_pluck( $terms, 'term_id' );

$tax_query = array(
    'relation'  => 'OR',
            array(
                'taxonomy'          =>  'category',
                'field'             => 'term_id',
                'terms'              => $term_ids,
            ),
    );
}

$wp_query = new \WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Its hard to help you fix your code when we don't know what the problem is :) What is going wrong with the code above? Also, you have cut out the unnecessary code thanks, but we don't know what all your variables are so can you also replace them to example values so we can understand a bit better what your query is doing?

Comment: I appreciate what you're asking, however, I'm OK with the other variables.. the query works fine without the tax query. Really the only part you're missing is `$wp_query = new \WP_Query($args);`
Giving the full code here is fairly complex and I deem it unnecessary as my question is related to the tax_query only..

Comment: *You* might be fine with the other variables, but *we* don't know what they are! You should try to make it as easy as possible for us when you're asking us for help :) If we were to try to recreate your problem in our own dev environments to help you debug the problem, we need to know exactly what we're dealing with because we don't have those vars set up.

Comment: Fair point. maybe I should have just excluded them for the purpose of this question. I'm not sure how to redo this question keeping things that is of concern and not. the whole function is over 300 lines long. haha

Comment: Yes probably :). The point of a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) is so we don't need to worry about the code that is ok and also that it isn't having an inadvertent effect on the problem. That said, now that you clarify that it works without the tax_query, we know where to look... is this the `tax_query` *exactly* as it is in your code? In that case, its just a typo... you have a `;`after the tax_query array instead of a `,`

Comment: Yeah, fair enough. I've edited the question & made some adjustments to it, hopefully for easier read and "minimal, reproducible example".  (also not using the accidental `;` any longer)

Comment: Bad news... doesn't look like this is easily done after all... I've added a few links [in the chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216641/discussion-between-sandy-garrido-and-fluffykitten) to check out for reference. You might need to look at doing this another way I'm afraid!

Comment: @FluffyKitten thank you for all your help. 1 hour ago, we both gave up on it. I've done it!! and it was by your final solution from chat.

Comment: That’s fantastic!!!! Well done, so glad you got sorted! If you ever get the time, you can add your answer here to help anyone else struggling with this. Excuse me, *I* didn’t give up on it :p my old project architecting skills were just kicking in! I knew we were there with that last outline, I could see the whole thing in my head for the first time. I told you it wasn’t out of your reach to do! Now if only I could have the same breakthrough with my own work :)